# Qualcomm Atheros qca61x4 network adapter not working

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, atheros, 16.04

I have looked at almost every similar question and tried the suggestions and answers people have given with no luck as of yet. I was on ubuntu 15.10 but just recently upgraded to 16.04 hoping that maybe there would be official support for my card now. From my understanding my card requires the ath10k drivers and have tried installing backports of those when I was on 15.10 and I tried using ndiswrapper with the windows drivers.
I am still fairly new to ubuntu so I apologize in advance for not knowing a lot.
Here are some terminal readouts:

```
alex@alex-Lenovo-Edge-15:~$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac
Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

Now I seem have to been able to gotten the ath10k firmware to run, I think, although it refuses to start on boot, but manually starting it with 'modprobe ath10k_pci' cause it to now show up when running lsmod when prior to that command it couldn't be found on lsmod

```
alex@alex-Lenovo-Edge-15:~$ lsmod | grep ath
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,mac80211,r8188eu,ath10k_core
```

Also worth noting is that my adapter used to show up as Unclaimed when running lshw -C network but now doesn't

```
alex@alex-Lenovo-Edge-15:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
```

Despite this, iwconfig still shows nothing for my adapter and ubuntu seems to have no clue how to use it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Here are more requested terminal commands

```
alex@alex-Lenovo-Edge-15:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3545]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

alex@alex-Lenovo-Edge-15:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Alright, I added the requested commands. Hopefully they can help you figure out what my issue is.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title.  Post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution.

So I guess because I didn't do a clean install for 16.04 the windows driver I had tried to install (unsuccessfully) with ndiswrapper was still there, not sure if that is the whole problem. Running 'modprobe ath10k_pci' would start up the correct driver firmware however looking at dmesg I realized it wasn't loading correctly. The firmware I got was from here (https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware). Weirdly enough, although lspci told me my card was the 6164, the firmware it was trying to load was from the 6174 folder, the issue is it was trying to load from a hw2.1 folder which did not exist when I downloaded the firmware from the git link. I manually downloaded the files for 6174 hw2.1 from the git link and had to create that folder in lib/firmware/ath10k/6174 and paste the files in. That still didn't work so I went back in and renamed one of the files to firmware-5.bin from it's original name (firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1). After a reboot it still didn't work until I ran the 'sudo modprobe ath10k_pci' command. Lo and behold, it now works...provided I manually start up the correct firmware each boot.

Again, for newbies like me, to do the file operations, you must run 'sudo nautilus' to get sudo access in the file manager.

Hopefully my lengthy solution will help those like me who aren't very familiar with ubuntu.